# Construction of a certain cutoff function (also known as "mollifier")

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given a one-dimensional closed and bounded interval, say $[0,L]$ for some $L > 0$, and fix $\epsilon >0$ to be sufficiently small, i.e., $\epsilon \ll 1$. May I know does there exists a smooth non-negative function (let's call it $f$) on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \equiv 0$ for $x \in (-\infty,0] \cup [L,\infty)$ and $f(x) \equiv 1$ for $x \in [\epsilon, L-\epsilon]$ ? I am more eager to see an explicit example of such a function if possible, I would appreciate any help or reference related to this question.

---

Edit: If possible, I hope such construction does not involve summation of a series.

Comment: @Thomas I of course have checked the wiki, this does not solve my problem.

Comment: I want $f$ to be identically $1$ on a "large" interval (almost of size $L - 0 = L$), if it sounds too easy to you, you don't you give a sketch of the "scaling" and "translating" you are referring to? Your newly posted wiki is highly non-trivial and I just want to convince you that the details are not that easy

Comment: combine the article on mollification with this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity - subdivide the interval in question in subintervals of length $ \varepsilon$, construct a partition of unity subordinate to that partition, and sum the functions (there are finitely many only) on all intevals with the exception of those at the boundary. (I do not claim it's easy. But it is well known).

Comment: "Well-known" is a pretty bad phrase in my opinion, mathematicians all have different background, and as you said, you do not claim it's easy, so why do you claim it's well-known then?

Comment: Because it _is_ well known. These kind of functions are used extensively in analysis to get global results from local ones. This is a well established technique which is taught in every course on analysis, the latest when it comes to integration theory.

Comment: @Thomas I am ready to offer bounties to this "well-known" fact. Please note that in my edited post, I want a explicit example which does not involving summation of a series.

Comment: A theoretical answer is to take the convolution of the characteristic function of $[O,L]$ with a smooth function with support on $[0,\varepsilon]$. Besides @Thomas I don't see the need to consider a partition of unity.

Comment: @JeanMarie May I know a explicitly written example? Nothing is more transparent than a explicit definition of $f$

Comment: I said that it is theoretical answer ! An example of a smooth $C^n$ function with support on [0,\varepsilon] : a "cardinal spline" with degree $n+1$ (have you heard about these functions which are defined as convolution powers of characteristic functions ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually I have no clue as to the "cardinal spline". I hope such example does not involve summation of a series.

Comment: In fact, more practically, see this question and its answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/799567

Comment: Unless you receive an answer by the weekend consider pinging me again and I may find the time on Saturday or Sunday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered for example by my answer to [Smooth function passing through a countable number of points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4343975).

The lemma proved there says that there exists a smooth ($C^\infty$) function $f_0 :  \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f_0 = 0$ on $(-\infty,0]$ and $f_0 = 1$ on $[\epsilon,\infty)$. The function $f_0$ is given *explicitly* in the proof of the lemma and you see that $f_0(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x$.

Define
$$f(x) = f_0(x) \cdot f_0(L - x). $$

This is clearly a smooth function. We have

1. $f_0(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x$
2. $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-\infty,0]$ and $x \in [L,\infty)$.
3. $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [\epsilon,L-\epsilon]$.

Comment: The construction you give in your (referenced) answer can be found also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, it is similar. But the function in the Wikipedia-link has a maximum exactly at $0$ and must be adjusted to give a "Urysohn-function".

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer.